# Video streaming using NanoHttpd, Error: java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)

Tags: java, android, nanohttpd

I need to stream a video and play continuously in a webpage. I am using Nanohttpd library to run the server in my Android app. I can able to stream and play the video when the page loads. Once the video completes playing I can't able to play the video for second time. Every time I need to refresh the page to play the video. I get the following error while trying to play for the second time.

```
java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:546)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:515)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:504)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:266)
    at server.http.android.androidhttpserver.server.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBody(NanoHTTPD.java:1386)
    at server.http.android.androidhttpserver.server.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBodyWithCorrectEncoding(NanoHTTPD.java:1359)
    at server.http.android.androidhttpserver.server.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBodyWithCorrectTransferAndEncoding(NanoHTTPD.java:1349)
    at server.http.android.androidhttpserver.server.NanoHTTPD$Response.send(NanoHTTPD.java:1335)
    at server.http.android.androidhttpserver.server.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.execute(NanoHTTPD.java:769)
    at server.http.android.androidhttpserver.server.NanoHTTPD$ClientHandler.run(NanoHTTPD.java:186)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
    at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:176)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:278)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:513)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:504)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:266)
    at server.http.android.androidhttpserver.server.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBody(NanoHTTPD.java:1386)
    at server.http.android.androidhttpserver.server.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBodyWithCorrectEncoding(NanoHTTPD.java:1359)
    at server.http.android.androidhttpserver.server.NanoHTTPD$Response.sendBodyWithCorrectTransferAndEncoding(NanoHTTPD.java:1349)
    at server.http.android.androidhttpserver.server.NanoHTTPD$Response.send(NanoHTTPD.java:1335)
    at server.http.android.androidhttpserver.server.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.execute(NanoHTTPD.java:769)
    at server.http.android.androidhttpserver.server.NanoHTTPD$ClientHandler.run(NanoHTTPD.java:186)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I am sending the response as follows.

```
@Override
public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
   FileInputStream fis = null;
    File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VIDEO.mp4");
    try{
        if(file.exists())
        {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        }
        else
         Log.d("FOF :", "File Not exists:");
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new NanoHTTPD.Response(Response.Status.OK,"video/mp4",fis, file.length() );
}
```

The HTML file to access the video is

```
<html><body>
<video id="video_id" width="420" autoplay loop>
    <source src=http://192.168.2.6:8080/ type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</body></html>
```

Please provide me a solution to play the video continuously without refreshing the web page.

Answer (score 3):

I successfully with following codes:

```
@Override
public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
    Map<String, String> headers = session.getHeaders();
    Map<String, String> parms = session.getParms();
    Method method = session.getMethod();
    String uri = session.getUri();
    Map<String, String> files = new HashMap<>();

    if (Method.POST.equals(method) || Method.PUT.equals(method)) {
        try {
            session.parseBody(files);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            return getResponse("Internal Error IO Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (ResponseException e) {
            return new Response(e.getStatus(), MIME_PLAINTEXT, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    uri = uri.trim().replace(File.separatorChar, '/');
    if (uri.indexOf('?') >= 0) {
        uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf('?'));
    }

    File f = new File(uri);
    return serveFile(uri, header, f);
}

private Response serveFile(String uri, Map<String, String> header, File file) {
    Response res;
    String mime = getMimeTypeForFile(uri);
    try {
        // Calculate etag
        String etag = Integer.toHexString((file.getAbsolutePath() +
                file.lastModified() + "" + file.length()).hashCode());

        // Support (simple) skipping:
        long startFrom = 0;
        long endAt = -1;
        String range = header.get("range");
        if (range != null) {
            if (range.startsWith("bytes=")) {
                range = range.substring("bytes=".length());
                int minus = range.indexOf('-');
                try {
                    if (minus > 0) {
                        startFrom = Long.parseLong(range.substring(0, minus));
                        endAt = Long.parseLong(range.substring(minus + 1));
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
                }
            }
        }

        // Change return code and add Content-Range header when skipping is requested
        long fileLen = file.length();
        if (range != null && startFrom >= 0) {
            if (startFrom >= fileLen) {
                res = createResponse(Response.Status.RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE, MIME_PLAINTEXT, "");
                res.addHeader("Content-Range", "bytes 0-0/" + fileLen);
                res.addHeader("ETag", etag);
            } else {
                if (endAt < 0) {
                    endAt = fileLen - 1;
                }
                long newLen = endAt - startFrom + 1;
                if (newLen < 0) {
                    newLen = 0;
                }

                final long dataLen = newLen;
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file) {
                    @Override
                    public int available() throws IOException {
                        return (int) dataLen;
                    }
                };
                fis.skip(startFrom);

                res = createResponse(Response.Status.PARTIAL_CONTENT, mime, fis);
                res.addHeader("Content-Length", "" + dataLen);
                res.addHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + startFrom + "-" +
                        endAt + "/" + fileLen);
                res.addHeader("ETag", etag);
            }
        } else {
            if (etag.equals(header.get("if-none-match")))
                res = createResponse(Response.Status.NOT_MODIFIED, mime, "");
            else {
                res = createResponse(Response.Status.OK, mime, new FileInputStream(file));
                res.addHeader("Content-Length", "" + fileLen);
                res.addHeader("ETag", etag);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        res = getResponse("Forbidden: Reading file failed");
    }

    return (res == null) ? getResponse("Error 404: File not found") : res;
}

// Announce that the file server accepts partial content requests
private Response createResponse(Response.Status status, String mimeType, InputStream message) {
    Response res = new Response(status, mimeType, message);
    res.addHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
    return res;
}

// Announce that the file server accepts partial content requests
private Response createResponse(Response.Status status, String mimeType, String message) {
    Response res = new Response(status, mimeType, message);
    res.addHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
    return res;
}

private Response getResponse(String message) {
    return createResponse(Response.Status.OK, "text/plain", message);
}
```

Comment: What does getResponse() method defines?

Comment: private Response getResponse(String message) {
        return createResponse(Response.Status.OK, "text/plain", message);
}

Comment: I am getting the following warning in NanoHTTPD.java

'serve(java.lang.String, server.http.android.androidhttpserver.server.NanoHTTPD.Method, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>)' is deprecated 

This inspection reports where deprecated code is used in the specified inspection scope.

Comment: What version of NanoHTTPD are you using? I'm using version 2.1.0

Comment: I have updated above coding by adding serve() method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and my code works perfectly as expected...
The only change that I have done was, edited the parameters of 'Response' as mentioned here 
'Response res = new Response(IStatus status, String mimeType, InputStream data, long totalBytes);'